# Which SQLite and connection method should I use with WPF in VS2010 C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to create a .NET WPF application in VS2010 C# but I'm confused over the SQLite downloads and the connection methods available.

First some suggest using the [ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/) while they also say that it is using .NET 2.0 code, so I have to use the [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) attribute:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true|false" > 
</startup>
```

Is this the right approach? Any disadvantages of this attribute?

Second I can't decide which package to download from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki. There is no info if the x64 version will work correctly on x86 systems, also I couldn't find info about the differences between: the simple "Setup", "Precompiled Binaries" and the "Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries".

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: In all likelihood x64 will not work on x86 architecture; however, in most instances (based on my experience), software written for x86 will work on x64 architecture.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I don't know if the x64 version contains the code for x86 systems. So which version should I use if I want my software to run on both x86 and x64 systems, and will my software run on x86 systems if I use the x64 version?

Comment: As I stated, in most instances, x86 software will work on both architectures. If you want the software to run on both x86 & x64, then, you will opt for the x86.

Comment: OK, thank you, so it is the x86 version which I need. Could you help with the other questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with SQLite so I would not be able to provide you with anything useful ...sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet, search for SQLIte and get the SQLite dll and the ADO.NET provider, NuGet will setup everything else...

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Seems to be an interesting project, never heard of it before, but this is something I would like to setup by hand, and want to understand what was installed, where and why.

Comment: OK, I've tried to use NuGet, unfortunately it seems, that it doesn't support VS2010 Express editions.